# How to query two models under a class view, get specific attributes associated with each models and compare one record against another

Tags: django-models

I have two models Job and Applicants, the Job model has an attribute years_of_experience and the Applicants model has an attribute applicant_experience. I want to get the applicants years of experience and compare it the required years of experience for each particular job, and return only those that meet the requirement under a view.

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    years_of_experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Applicants(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applicants')
    experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
class QualifiedApplicantPerJobView(ListView):
    model = Applicants
    template_name = 'qualified_applicants.html'
    context_object_name = 'applicants'
    paginate_by = 2

    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('login')))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(self.request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Applicants.objects.filter(job_id=self.kwargs['job_id']).order_by('-id')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['job'] = Job.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['job_id'])
        return context
```

applicants.html

```
{% for applicant in applicants %}
   {% if applicant.experience >= job.years_of_experience %}
    <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="box applicant">
            <h4>{{ applicant.user.get_full_name }}</h4>
            <h4>{{ applicant.user.email }}</h4>
       </div>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't want to do it like this, I want to be able to do it in my views, get the number of qualified applicants(count) and return the qualified applicants. What is the best way to approach this. Thanks

Comment: This is [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter):    => "Multiple parameters are joined via AND in the underlying SQL statement"

Comment: The documentation helped

Comment: Django (and Python) are rather well documented indeed so using the doc usually saves a lot of time and pain ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra argument to `filter`.

Of course, you'll need to get the job for which you want to get available applicants first, so you can determine the `years_of_experience` required for the job with the specified ID.

You can then use the `__gte` filter argument to filter for applicants with an `experience` field greater than the required number of years. [This is specified under 'Field lookups' in the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)

To sum it all up:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # First we get the job itself.
    job = Job.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['job_id'])

    # Add an extra argument to the filter method.
    return Applicants.objects
                .filter(job=job, experience__gte = job.years_of_experience)
                .order_by('id')
```

You can then leave out the

`{% if applicant.experience >= job.years_of_experience %} ... {% endif %}`

statement from your template.

Comment: Nice. using the __gte and __lte or exclude(__gte) worked for greater than and less than respectively.

Comment: I tried getting the number(counnt) of qualified and pass it with a context to another template with     **qualified_count = Applicants.objects.filter(job=job, experience__gte=job.years_of_experience).count()** it didn't work. I did all this in a function based view. Any tips

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Did you get an incorrect count, or did it not pass at all?